# MvcSiteMapProvider using embedded resource file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, mvcsitemapprovider

Is it possible to localize mvcsitemapnodes by using a embedded resource file (so not using a resource file in App_GlobalResources)?

I found this solution: [Resource file for MVCSiteMapProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292155/resource-file-for-mvcsitemapprovider), but i'm not sure if it will work and how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Globalization in MVCSiteMapProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126620/globalization-in-mvcsitemapprovider)

Comment: Thnx for your comment. I'm still having trouble implementing your solution.I'm getting the following error when trying to set the cacheDetails.  Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'StructureMap.Pipeline.SmartInstance<MvcSiteMapProvider.Caching.CacheDetails,MvcSiteMapProvider.Caching.ICacheDetails>' to 'StructureMap.Pipeline.SmartInstance<MvcSiteMapProvider.Caching.CacheDetails>' Any idea how to fix this @NightOwl888?

Comment: If you install the NuGet package `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.StructureMap` you will have a working DI configuration. All you need to do is apply the modifications to it in the SO post above. There is no need to copy the entire DI config.

Comment: FYI - I just noticed that there appears to be a bug in NuGet where it doesn't install all dependencies. For this to work, you need to first install `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVCx` (where x is your MVC version) followed by the upgrade to `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVCx.DI.StructureMap`.